JavaFX gui broken text
I am trying to display a GUI using JavaFX
but any text in the gui is broken and buggy except the headers

I am using eclipse and edited several settings under
Window > Preferences > General > Appearance
but nothing worked and nothing changed

Which operating system? Which version of Java? Which version of JavaFX? And please provide a [mre].

Finally I managed to fix the issue:
I added:
scene.getRoot().setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'Arial';");

